# Flutter: byte array response body to file?

Tags: spring-boot, flutter, dart

From my spring-boot backend I return a Resource object:

```
@Override
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> get(Long id) {
        MyCustomFile entity = service.get(id);

        if (entity == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(toResource(entity), toHeaders(entity), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    protected Resource toResource(MyCustomFile myfile) {
        return toResource(myfile.getContent()); 
              // here the getContent() returns array of bytes: private byte[] content;
    }

    protected Resource toResource(byte[] data) {
        return new ByteArrayResource(data);
    }
```

I get the response in my flutter app:

```
  getFileById(int id, String token) async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse("$URL$id"), headers: {
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'bearer $token',
    });
  }
```

But how to turn this into a file? (jpg)

If I print the `response.body`:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Response` object has also `bodyBytes` field for directly getting bytes.

Here is a short working example:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<void> main() async {
  final url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg';
  final outputFilePath = 'example.jpg';
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  await File(outputFilePath).writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
}
```